# iOS, shared_ptr lifecycle in objective-c code?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, push

I use MonkSVG library which uses `boost::shared_ptr` type (as I understand `std::shared_ptr` works in this same way).

As I understand I don't need to free memory from it by myself.

I created a separate `UIViewController` with code from library example that defines shared_ptr variable and push/pop this view controller. But it seems something wrong with memory or this variable doesn't work in way I think. The problem is in the destructor of `shared_ptr` object:

I think that `shared_ptr` object's destructor must be called each time I pop the view controller with it. But it is called when I assign to this variable another instance only. It looks something like the following:

push/pop   |   shared_ptr   |   usual object

push   |   -   |   -

pop   |   -   |   destructor

push   |   destructor   |   -

pop   |   -   | destructor

etc.

Is it its normal behaviour?

Comment: Is your boost::shared_ptr an instance variable (ivar) of your UIViewController subclass?

Comment: I tried it as a static variable inside the file of `UIViewController` subclass (not inside this class) and I tried it as usual variable inside this class. The results are the same or look same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popping (I assume you mean in a `UINavigationController`) a `UIViewController` will not necessarily deallocate it (you can override its `dealloc` method to check that). The `UIViewController` instance will remain alive as long as you keep a strong reference to it.

However when you re-assign your `UIViewController` variable, you lose the strong reference to the old instance (if you a using ARC), which causes it to be deallocated, which then destroys any `shared_ptr` instance variables.

Comment: My object is declared as `shared_ptr obj;` is it possible to assign to it any empty value to reset it?

Comment: you have a shared_ptr to what?

Comment: thanks, reset works perfect. I didn't found it because I tried to add a method with the same name to the object type inside shared_ptr. At all I'm newbie in c++, but I need to fix a memory problem inside c++ library.